# Run Stored Procedures Asynchronously Asp.net mvc ef6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have to run a stored procedure that takes 3 parameters and returns a list of  mymodel

```
public IEnumerable<SPSalesbyBrandModel> ConvertoLinQSalesByBrand(string fromDate, string toDate, string category)
        {
            var queryResult = SPSalesbyBrandModelData.FromSql<SPSalesbyBrandModel>("dbo.SalesByBrand @StartDate, @EndDate, @Type",
                     new SqlParameter("StartDate", fromDate),
                     new SqlParameter("EndDate", toDate),
                     new SqlParameter("Type", category));
            return queryResult;      
        }
```

The query gets timed out and throws exception. I read about Task- await to run the statements asynchronously. What i am looking for is, I wanted to run the query asynchronously and return the result to the controller. As I'm new to asynchronous programming and asp.net, Can someone help to fix this and suggest the right approach to the problem? Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Have a look at this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/027d4e62-d1c3-4939-a84a-7038994cdfe2/asynchronous-sqldataadapter?forum=adodotnetdataset

Comment: Can we execute sqlcommands directly when using EF6. Without using SqlDataAdapter, i tried executing it. Got following exception:Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur is you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

Comment: So you don't want to do it asynchronously now as mentioned earlier?But its not a good approach to use sqlcommands with EF

Comment: In the link provided, they were using SqlCommands, even i don't want to use it, but process it asynchronously

Comment: If this is the case if you want to do it I tried it like this `Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessDB(e, queueID));
task.Wait();` >> By doing this you can process asynchronously too..

Comment: Could you please specify What is ProcessDB, e and queueID,Thanks!

Comment: That's clue for your understanding i.e ProcessDb is method and queueID is its parameter.

Comment: Implemented calling the method using async await. There is a mismatch in the Datetime parameter being passed to the stored procedure. What is the right way?

Comment: what is datatype for you parameter in SP?

Comment: return  await StoreCheckByDate.FromSql("exec dbo.StoreCheckByDate @StartDate, @EndDate", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(sdate,"MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(edate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).ToArrayAsync()

Comment: Datatype in SP is DateTime

Comment: You are making it complex by yourself. Simply set your `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` to varchar and convert to date in SP also. And from code send simple string

Comment: return  await StoreCheckByDate.FromSql("exec dbo.StoreCheckByDate @StartDate={0}, @EndDate={1}",sdate.ToString(),edate.ToString()).ToArrayAsync()

Comment: tried passing value as a string and in my sp changed type to varchar.

Comment: But i'm getting error:An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
lambda_method

Stack Query Cookies Headers
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
lambda_method
Shape

Comment: check this link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1121822/Using-Async-Await-Task-Methods-With-SQL-Queries-NE

Comment: SqlDataAdapter is not supported in entity framework core, i guess